# Difference between default(int?) vs (int?)null

Tags: c#

Is there any difference using `default(int?)` or `(int?)null` to assign a variable?

Is the same thing?

Or exists some pros and cons to use each way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're exactly the same thing, as is `new int?()`.

If you're just assigning a *variable*, you normally wouldn't need it at all though. I'd just use:

```
int? x = null;
```

for example.

The time I most often need one of these expressions is the conditional operator, e.g.

```
int y = ...;
int? z = condition ? default(int?) : y;
```

You can't use `null` in that scenario as the compiler can't infer the type of the expression. (Arguably that would be a useful addition to the language, mind you...)

Comment: In my case are a ternary operator as you exemplified var x = Int32.TryParse(entityObj.Prop, out result) ? result : (int?)null; I had to do this because this property is in a third party db stored as varchar. Thanks @jon-skeet

Answer (score 0):

Basically both are same. Default gives default value. For reference type and nullable type it gives null for value type it gives 0. If you decalre integer as nullable you can also assign it to `(int?)null`. you can check the IL code also just to verify.